# An error when executing pycrypto

Tags: python, odoo, pycrypto

I work with odoo and I want to install the module of paybox : this one : https://bitbucket.org/anybox/anybox_paybox/
For that : this module needs pycrypto to work

So, I installed  pycrypto in the linux server (ubuntu)

1. `git clone https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto.git`
2. `./configure`
3. `python setup.py build`
4. `python setup.py install`

and I made this test : python setup.py test 
Result there is no error but the problem comes here : in this file //paybox_signature.py//

```
# coding: utf-8
import urllib
import base64
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Hash import SHA

class Signature():

def verify(self, signature, msg, key):
    """ check if the signature is correct according to the public key path         given
        and the message """
    msg = self.remove_sign(msg)
    key = RSA.importKey(key)
    ha = SHA.SHA1Hash().new(msg)
    verifier = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
    signature = urllib.unquote(signature)
    signature = base64.b64decode(signature)
    return verifier.verify(ha, signature)

    def remove_sign(self, msg):
    """ remove signature arg from the given string"""
    pos = msg.find('&Signature')
    if pos == -1:
        return msg
    return msg[:pos]
```

when I execute this line of the file :

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
```

--> It ok there is no error

when I do this

```
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
```

--> Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in 
    ImportError: No module named Signature

I don't know Why 
All the modules are there why python make this error !! really I don't know 
Please I need your help Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Might be issue with the `pycrypto` package installation.

try with

```
sudo easy_install pycrypto
```

and than reboot your system.

You may also checkout [api of pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/2.6/)

If you use Mac OS than see more discussion [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1627)

Comment: I tried this and it generate this error : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2711, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: setuptools>=0.7

Answer (score 0):

Its an old question but for people who are still looking for answer and stumbling upon this page. You can download the pyCrypto from [pycrypto dist](https://ftp.dlitz.net/pub/dlitz/crypto/pycrypto/), but I recommend "pip install pyCrypto" as its simple and better.